# File path does not exist using here() and read_html()

Tags: html, r

I have a practice html file and want to load its contents using `here()` and `read_html()`. I have the following code:

```
path <- here("practice_recipe.html")
read_html(path)
```

However, I am getting this issue:
*Error: 'C:/Users/me/Documents/R_Projects/recipes/practice_recipe.html' does not exist.*

I confirmed the file path through the file explorer, but I'm not sure why this error message keeps popping up. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the output of `list.files()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Conor said, you have to make sure there is actually the file you're looking for:

```
"practice_recipe.html" %in% list.files() # probably FALSE
```

If it is FALSE, then move the HTML file into the folder given when you run `getwd()` (or `here()`)

Here is a working example:

```
library(rvest)

download.file("http://www.example.com", "example.html")

read_html("example.html")
```

Comment: Thanks! A folder ended up missing and I'm not sure why. The result of here() was 'C:/...recipes/practice_recipe.html' when it should have been 'C:/...recipes/practice/practice_recipe.html'. I fixed this with here("practice", "practice_recipe.html"). I'd appreciate any clarification as to why that one folder was skipped!

Comment: @NicholasRios glad I could help! I guess it's hard to know precisely the file structure you were going for. Sometimes I have an R project which I load, and then within that R project directory, I have a folder which I have all of my data in, `data`. Then I try to load one of the csvs with `read_csv("countries.csv")`, when I should be using `read_csv("data/countries.csv")`, if that makes sense?